# INDELS in PLINK files converted to VCF

Tags: vcf, variant-calling, plink, indel, validation

I want to compare/validate variants called from sequencing data with array (plink format) variant data. I converted the plink files (.bim, .bed, and .fam files) with plink1 to vcf files.

```
plink --bfile prefix_plink --recode vcf-iid --out prefix_out
```

However, the plink vcf files have "I" and "D" values for INDEL variants that cannot be compared and break the tools downstream (I am now using hap.py with rtgtools to validate). Is there a way to convert plink files to vcf, with some transformation of these I and D variants to a usable value? A "D" I could translate by hand to "" which is a vcf accepted format. But insertions require I guess a more complex procedure, or are even impossible (because they need to be compared to a reference genome)? Or am I missing some flag somewhere?

I would love to get some pointers and tips for this.

Kind regards,

Comment: I believe bcftools is able to accomplish this.